# Steam - Game crushes instantly (Mega Man Legacy Collection 2)

Tags: games, steam, error-handling

Problem: I try to run Mega Man Legacy Collection 2 on Steam (via Steam Play; Proton 4.2-2). Immediately after starting, the game crashes down. Disabling the in-game Steam Overlay in the game properties did not help.

I want to note that other games such as Counter-Strike: Source or Super Meat Boy work smoothly.

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Kernel: 4.4.0-134-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)

CPU: Dual core Intel Core i3-5010U (-HT-MCP-) 

Graphics: Card: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics 
          Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: intel
          Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
          GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
          GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

I have found this (quite lengthy) crash-log:

```
Proton: 1553870914 proton-4.2-2
SteamGameId: 495050
Command: ['/home/my_username/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/MegaMan2/MMLC2.exe']
```

here are the error lines of it:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/my_username/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/my_username/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored. 

Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
```

Maybe the last line is also important:

```
pid 8324 != 8323, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
```

I also want to mention that according to here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting#Wrong_ELF_class, the first two errors can be ignored.
Any ideas?

Comment: Proton/wine is a really complex piece of software and it does not claim to always work properly. It could be that the game is just causing proton to crash due to a bug.